# MapTreeStructure Export As Map

Tags: java, dictionary, tree

The following codes are aimed to export tree data structure into `Map<String, String>` so that can be easier to manipulate later. But the funny thing is `toString()` method works flawlessly but `toMap()` method **got one missing parent A, child B**. Anyone has any idea?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        MutableTree<String> tree = new MappedTreeStructure<String>();
        tree.add("A", "B");
        tree.add("A", "C");
        tree.add("C", "D");
        tree.add("E", "F");
        System.out.println(tree);

        Map<String, String> myMap = tree.toMap();
        if (myMap != null) {
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : myMap.entrySet()) {
                System.out.println("parent: " + entry.getKey() + ", child: "
                        + entry.getValue());
            }
        }

    }

    private final Map<N, N> nodeParent = new HashMap<N, N>();
    private final LinkedHashSet<N> nodeList = new LinkedHashSet<N>();

    @Override
    public boolean add(N parent, N node) {

        boolean added = nodeList.add(node);
        nodeList.add(parent);
        if (added) {
            nodeParent.put(node, parent);
        }
        return added;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean remove(N node, boolean cascade) {
        if (!nodeList.contains(node)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (cascade) {
            for (N child : getChildren(node)) {
                remove(child, true);
            }
        } else {
            for (N child : getChildren(node)) {
                nodeParent.remove(child);
            }
        }
        nodeList.remove(node);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public List<N> getRoots() {
        return getChildren(null);
    }

    @Override
    public N getParent(N node) {
        return nodeParent.get(node);
    }

    @Override
    public List<N> getChildren(N node) {
        List<N> children = new LinkedList<N>();
        for (N n : nodeList) {
            N parent = nodeParent.get(n);
            if (node == null && parent == null) {
                children.add(n);
            } else if (node != null && parent != null && parent.equals(node)) {
                children.add(n);
            }
        }
        return children;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        dumpNodeStructure(builder, null, "- ");
        return builder.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> toMap() {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        dumpNodeToMap(map, null);
        return map;
    }

    private void dumpNodeToMap(Map<String, String> map, N node) {
        if (node != null) {
            map.put((String) getParent(node), node.toString());
        }
        for (N child : getChildren(node)) {
            dumpNodeToMap(map, child);
        }
    }

    private void dumpNodeStructure(StringBuilder builder, N node, String prefix) {

        if (node != null) {

            builder.append(prefix);
            builder.append(node.toString());
            builder.append('\n');
            prefix = "    " + prefix;
        }

        for (N child : getChildren(node)) {
            dumpNodeStructure(builder, child, prefix);
        }

    }
```

The output are following on console:

```
- A
    - B
    - C
        - D
- E
    - F

parent: null, child: E
parent: A, child: C
parent: C, child: D
parent: E, child: F
```

For references, these are the two interface classes being used:

```
public interface MutableTree <N extends Serializable> extends Tree<N> {
    public boolean add (N parent, N node);
    public boolean remove (N node, boolean cascade);
    Map<String, String> toMap();
}
```

and

```
public interface Tree <N extends Serializable> extends Serializable {
    public List<N> getRoots ();
    public N getParent (N node);
    public List<N> getChildren (N node);
}
```

Comment: Where is the declaration of the parameterized type `N` for this class?

Comment: Included interface class of MutableTree and Tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `toMap` method returns a a `Map<String, String>` whose key is the parent element name and whose value is a *single* child element. This means that when the key is "A" only one child element can be stored, and this is being set to the last child element which is found, in this case "C", overwriting the entry for "A" which was pointing to "B".

Instead your `toMap` method needs to return a `Map<String, List<String>>` which maps from each parent node, such as "A", to a `List` of child elements, such as "B" and "C". Obviously it's fine if the `List` contains only one child element, but it must be a list in case there is more than one child.

The usual pattern for creating a `List` of items rather than a single item looks like this:

```
String parentNode = getParent(node).toString();
List<String> childElements = null;
if(map.contains(parentNode) {
    // List of child elements already exists, so get it from the Map.
    childElements = map.get(parentNode);
} else {
    // List of child elements does not yet exist, so create a new List
    // and add it to the Map.
    childElements = new ArrayList<>();
    map.put(parentNode, childElements);
}
childElements.add(node.toString());
```

Comment: Thanks for the code example, I had rewrite the toMap() method. Will update above.